# JLabel and Icon centered to each other in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, constraints, gridbaglayout

I have a panel with this layout:

[image]

There is a JLabel with the following `labelConstraints` in front of the icon and the icon has the `lastConstraints` to display after a JLabel:

```
  GridBagConstraints lastConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
  GridBagConstraints labelConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();

  lastConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  lastConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
  lastConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
  lastConstraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
  lastConstraints.insets = new Insets(8, 4, 8, 8);

  labelConstraints = (GridBagConstraints) lastConstraints.clone();
  labelConstraints.weightx = 0.0;
  labelConstraints.gridwidth = 1;
```

Now I want to have the icons (or the JLabel) centered in relation to the label (or the icon), like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this? I don't want to put the icon into the JLabel as I need it to be in it's own JLabel (cause I want to change the icon later).

Comment: how is possible that two elements in same row has..., disable Insets,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try

```
lastConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to put the icon on the label; you can change the icon at any time using `setIcon()`. Alternatively, use either [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#alignment) alignment or [`GroupLayout.Alignment`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html).